# Magento 2: Getting a Product URL from the API

Tags: product, magento2, api, url

In Magento 2, it is possible to get a product's URL using the information returned via the API/Repositories?

That is, when grabbing a list of products from the API, the `url_key` will be returned as part of the `custom_attribute` array.

```
  8 => 
    array (size=2)
      'attribute_code' => string 'url_key' (length=7)
      'value' => string 'joust-duffle-bag' (length=16)
```

However, the actual product URL in the system will not be returned.

Is there a way, using only the API, to get a product's actual URL?

Or am I mistaken, and calls to the ProductRepository API method should include the URL.  If so, what should those calls look like?

Or does this question not make sense due to the way Magento 2 handles product URLs?  If so, what's "dumb" about this question?

I realize it's possible, using the provided PHP objects, to use a `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url` object with an instantiated `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` object.  What I'm looking for is an "API only" way to return a product's URL.

Comment: Hi Alan - I don't believe we support that feature.  what use cases do you need to support so an API call returns the product page's URL?

Comment: @Chuck Theoretical Use Case: Third Party Email Newsletter Application wants to fetch product information to include in a newsletter, and wants a link to the product page so it can embed an HTML link to the product page.

Comment: Another use case: some affiliate tracking code requires the product URL.

Comment: Alan, I very much agree and was told that this feature was in the product backlog.  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10276#issuecomment-316124070  In the meantime, you can use product ID as I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After extensive research and two months of being open, it seems the answer to this question is No.  The Magento 2 API can't be used to directly fetch a product URL.

Answer (score 3):

The value `url_key` (which is returned by the Products API) can be used to build a URL for some products - for example, product 547 in the test dataset has `url_key` = "zoltan-gym-tee", and you can do

http://YOUR-SITE.com/zoltan-gym-tee.html

and it works.

You may also use the product ID (returned in the Products API) to build a URL.

For product 541, this would be

http://YOUR-SITE.com/catalog/product/view/id/541

For either of these to work, be sure the visibility flag is set correctly for this product in Admin->Products->Catalog. The visibility must include "Catalog."

Comment: +1 for useful information (and that's the work around we ended up going with), but this approach isn't without its problems.  What if a system has the `.html` file extensions turned off for URLs, or has rewrite rules that don't use the `url_key`?  Or what happens with parent/child products (configurable/simple, bundle, etc.) when you start building URLs with raw controller actions and IDs.  Easy enough to fix on a local level, hard to know what the right thing to do for redistributable code is.

Comment: @AlanStorm Agreed!  That's why I nagged them to fix.  (See my comment on your question.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an api search query as below, to target the `url_key` by using a combination of searchCriteria and fields https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/retrieve-filtered-responses.html

We also use the fields to filter the response and only return the information we need

```
https://www.domain.com/rest/V1/products? // url
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=sku& // search for field sku
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=neq& // not equal to
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=null& // null (we do this to target all products)
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][field]=type_id& // target the type of product
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][condition_type]=in& // where in
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][1][value]=configurable,giftcard& // configurable, giftcard (these products are the products you can view in the store)
searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][2][field]=website_id& // we target the website_id to shrink our product scope to a website
searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][2][condition_type]=eq& // website_id equal too
searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][2][value]=1& // website id 
searchCriteria[filter_groups][3][filters][3][field]=status& // we target the status to shrink the product result set even more
searchCriteria[filter_groups][3][filters][3][condition_type]=eq& // equal to
searchCriteria[filter_groups][3][filters][3][value]=1& // enabled
fields=items[sku,type_id,created_at,updated_at,custom_attributes[publish_date,url_key]] // we are only interested in the following fields
```

An example response looks like

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "sku": "XYZ123",
            "type_id": "configurable",
            "created_at": "2019-05-24 23:48:42",
            "updated_at": "2021-07-30 10:18:29",
            "custom_attributes": {
                "1": {
                    "attribute_code": "url_key",
                    "value": "xyz-123"
                },
                "7": {
                    "attribute_code": "publish_date",
                    "value": "2020-09-29 00:00:00"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "sku": "ABCDEF",
            "type_id": "configurable",
            "created_at": "2019-05-24 23:52:25",
            "updated_at": "2021-05-28 22:21:35",
            "custom_attributes": {
                "1": {
                    "attribute_code": "url_key",
                    "value": "product-abc-def"
                }
            }
        },
```

From there you can construct it by hand as example
`http://www.domain.com/[store_code]/[url_key](.html)`